# What is a program similar to WinSCP?

Tags: scp

In Windows I use WinSCP to transfer files server-side. It has a very attractive feature that I like best: keeping remote folders up to date.

This means, whenever my local file is changed, WinScp will replace the same file on the server with this new file.

Could you suggest me software that support this feature?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Nautilus the default file browser has the feature of mounting remote files.

Go to File Menu > Connect to Server..

[image]

Other than that `filezilla` and `gftp` support sftp.

Comment: caja has this too!

Comment: but does help me to access files/folders as a sudo user. Is there any way to use sudo with Nautilius?

Comment: Just do `gksu nautilus` to run `nautilus` as sudo user

Comment: Nemo (default on Mint) supports this too (go to sftp://<user>@<host>)

Comment: On your file-system these magic `sftp://...` links are stored in: `/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp*` (Of course your user id and sftp folder name will vary).

Comment: I am getting this page ( https://anonmgur.com/up/5a97de9b3038915650fde0a23f63b267.png ) instead of specifying new details. How do i correct it ?

Comment: Same as @maan81 here... I only see Serve Addres, and a smb://foo.example.org 
Running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: filezilla still doesn't support scp protocol. Most people in this thread assume he was using win**SCP** program for SFTP, but he even tagged this question with **SCP** tag.

Comment: The one bad thing about using gvfs / this method is that depending on your editor / application saving file changes.. Will re-create the file instead of just overwriting and this results in a change of ownership and permissions... Hence for my current project i'm searching for a filezilla alternative as filezilla  requires me to alt tab to it and wait for it to detect a change and then ask me if i want to confirm the upload... THIS is a royal pain in the ... and slows my development speed masssively...

Comment: How do I cd and navigate into this directory locally, in Terminal? Can I?

Comment: There is no "File Menu" any more...

Answer (score 42):

Since you are familiar with Winscp on Windows, I suggest 
that you try [filezilla](http://packages.ubuntu.com/filezilla)

FileZilla Client is a fast and reliable cross-platform FTP, FTPS and SFTP client with lots of useful features and an intuitive graphical user interface.

[image: Install filezilla]

You can also install with the command line. Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command:

```
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

Or search on Filezilla in Ubuntu Software Center.

When you add a host, be sure to change from FTP to SFTP, and change
the port number to ssh port 22 (or other custom ssh port if different)

Make the account type interactive.

Enjoy.

Comment: Unfortunately, filezilla still does not support ssh keys with passwords.

Comment: filezilla still doesn't support scp protocol. Most people in this thread assume he was using win**SCP** program for SFTP, but he even tagged this question with **SCP** tag.

Comment: I came here for exactly this: looking for SCP. SFTP is ubiquitous in most file managers in linux nowadays. Other than using scp CLI and winscp over wine i see nothing close to answering the actual question.

Comment: I wanted to follow up that filezilla does in fact support ssh keys with passphrases in them. Specifically, I am using it with a 2048bit rsa key using passphrases. However, it does whine a lot about ssh key formats. I am using version 3.28.0.

Comment: worked fine for me on ec2 using sftp

Comment: Sought to guify an `scp` command for our non-technical volunteers, FileZilla works like a boss.

Answer (score 25):

You could also use `sshfs` or `rsync`.

`sshfs` mounts your remote directory locally over ssh very similar to WinSCP and Nautilus.

The potential advantage of `sshfs` is that you can map users

```
sshfs -o idmap=server_user user@server:/directory ~/remote_directory
```

To automate the process, add an entry in fstab

```
sshfs#user@server:/directory /home/your_local_user/directory fuse idmap=user 0 0
```

See [Ubuntu Wiki SSHFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS)

`rsync` will also sync files / directories and will work over ssh and has a graphical front end, `grsync`

See [Ubuntu wiki rsync](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync)

Last you can edit remote files with `vim` (if you are interested)

```
vim scp://user@server//path_to/file_to_edit
```

Answer (score 13):

You can still use winscp under wine. I am doing the same, and it works very good.

Answer (score 6):

You want "[scp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/scp.1.html)". The original scp :-)

Oops, I spoke too soon... you have requirement of syncing as well. In that case, rsync.

However, scp is still good for scripts and automation.

Comment: I think someone using winscp would not be as excited to use scp in the command line. 
And one of the features one looks for in a gui sftp client is management of the different sessions one could use.

Comment: @viyyer, yes you're right.

Answer (score 5):

## Ubuntu:

Open Nautilus and type (in the link bar): `sftp://user@server/`

## Kubuntu:

Open Konqueror and type (in the link bar): `fish://user@server/`

## Xubuntu:

Open Thunar and type (in the link bar): `sftp://user@server/`

Comment: He asked specifically about SCP, while all of these use sftp. These are not the same thing. Also, the question was specifically about a syncing feature which none of these provide.

Comment: From winscp website:
Free Award-Winning File Manager
WinSCP is a popular SFTP client and FTP client...

He asked specifically abaut **WinSCP** (not _SCP_) and winscp is a Filemanager for ssh.
Nautilus, Konqueror and Thunar are filemanager too.

Comment: fwiw: (1) https://superuser.com/questions/134901/whats-the-difference-between-scp-and-sftp and (2) as of OpenSSH 8.0 "The scp protocol is outdated, inflexible and not readily fixed. We recommend the use of more modern protocols like sftp and rsync for file transfer instead" and (3) as of OpenSSH 9.0 "This release switches `scp` from using the legacy scp/rcp protocol to using the SFTP protocol by default." https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-9.0

Answer (score 3):

There are many different tools which would give a similar experience as winscp. I use filezilla for transferring files across ssh.

Nautilus as mentioned by @sagarchalise allows for connecting to server.

One of the things I use more often these days to access sftp is sshfs. I find it very convenient as it mounts the files as local file in the filesystem and transparently updates it on the remote server.

`sshfs username@remotehostname.tld:/path/to/remote/files /path/to/local/mountpoint/`

It lets me use all my usual tools assuming these file are local files.

Comment: This is very nice when you only can access thru SSH! I also recommend adding a couple of options: `follow symlinks` and `reconnect` (pretty much self explanatory, fixed freezing problems I had).    
Final command would be: `sshfs -o follow_symlinks -o reconnect username@remotehostname.tld:/path/to/remote/files /path/to/local/mountpoint/`. Also recommend to create a simple bash script to mount it (and unmount it with `fusermount -u /path/to/local/mountpoint/`).

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to help synchronize the two folders

Comment: Looks like unison needs a client on the remote server too? :(

Answer (score 2):

A very nice and powerful program, built over the `rsync` protocol, is [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

[image]

It has a very nice interface, and the client is available for at least Linux (more or less all variants) and Windows. The basic behavior is very easy to grasp, with a graphic interface and easy configuration, and if you need to do more complex things, you can manually edit the configuration files and/or script it.

It has been my backup/mirroring/uploading utility in the last five year at least, and never saw a bug or missed a file.

You can install it with

```
 sudo apt-get install unison-gtk
```

and for a smooth behavior, you should have configured a working connection with your endpoint (I normally use ssh connections).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend PCManFM `sudo apt-get install pcmanfm`

Just another File Manager but features a mini GUI for connections (in main menu Go --> Connect to server) and there you go. You can bookmark your connections and you can just right click files and chose "open with...".

Comment: Not only PCManFM, but most File Managers support it: Nautilus, Nemo, Caja, Dolphin at least do.

Comment: @the_Seppi: I agree, but I had problems with other file managers (mainly  connection hanged and had to kill the manager). But didn't try Dolphin, will try it just to see

Answer (score 2):

[Krusader](https://krusader.org/) is very similar if you need the side by side panel.

Simply install with

```
sudo apt install krusader
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what about "keeping remote folders up to date"?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest SecPanel https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/saucy/secpanel/ especially if you're using 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

To run WinSCP under Linux (Ubuntu 12.04), follow these steps:

1) `sudo apt-get install wine` (run this one time only, to get 'wine' in your system, if you haven't it)

2) download "https://winscp.net/"

3) make a folder and put the content of zip file in this folder

4) open a terminal

5) type `sudo su`

6) type `wine WinSCP.exe`

Done! WinSCP will run like in Windows environment!

Best regards.

Comment: Why run wine as super user? Don't do that. Skip step 5.

Answer (score 0):

I found one good standalone alternative, free, opensource, [mucommander](http://www.mucommander.com/), but java based, your system need to have jvm to run it.

Why I went for mucommander (I am using RHEL6 with ristrictions)?
1st I tried to connect with nautilus, but it failed to connect.
2nd I tried to use various s/w like filezilla, Unison , but nothing was standalone, and faced many compilation and rights issue.

Ulitmately mucommander saved me.
Deep