# How can I connect to a server via SCP in Lubuntu 15?

Tags: ssh, lubuntu, nautilus, scp, pcmanfm

In Windows I can use WinSCP. In the question [What is a program similar to WinSCP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94665/what-is-a-program-similar-to-winscp), it says that you can use Nautilus’s built-in function to do this job. But in Lubuntu there’s only PCManFM. I tried to replace it with Nautilus but failed. Is there any simple way for me to have a SCP client in Lubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a SCP client with a GUI, than you could try [filezilla](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=filezilla):

```
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

Use `sftp` as protocol (eg: `sftp://myhost`) in the *Host* field as *Port* `22`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

PCManFM supports mounting of network file shares.

In the main menu, select Go > Connect to Server...

[image: Go > Connect to Server...]

I'm not familiar with WinSCP, but I assume it uses SSH. To mount an SSH share, select SSH and fill in the appropriate information, including at least the host, port (if other than 22), and user.

[image: SSH connection screen]

Enter your password and how long you'd like to remain connected:

[image: Enter password & timeout]

And you're in! You can browse your files, and open/delete/edit/move them (assuming you have appropriate permissions), all within PCManFM.

[image: Browsing Pictures on SSH mounted share in PCManFM]

Answer (score 1):

Although this has already been checked by the author, I wanted to mention a couple more choices.

First I apologize for items 5. It is command line but interesting. For your question, look at items (1), (4) and (6).

1. **pcmanfm** is native to LUbuntu (since you asked about Lubuntu which I use). The answer about PCManFM is very relevant since it already incorporates the requested functionality.  From its menu:

   `Select "GO | Go to Location" 
    Select ssh`

To install this filemanager:

```
sudo apt-get install pcmanfm
```

2. **Nautilus** file manager ships with many distros (and is popular - though not my favorite).  It will  do what you ask natively.

   In the left-hand pane select the `Connect to Server` icon.
   In the server address blank type `ssh://server_name`

It is actually using sftp (you could have typed sftp://server_name) so setting up ssh keys is recommended over passwords, but not required.

Nautilus may be installed on your distro already.  If not, you can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

additionally, there are other things nautilus can do like connect to owncloud, dropbox and much more.  For these two:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-owncloud
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

In general look at the list from the command `apt-cache dumpavail | grep Package | grep nautilus` to see how extensible it is.  I note the nautilus scripting capability.

I suspect that most file managers have similar functionality.

3. **Filezilla** which is extremely well explained in an answer above.
4. **gftp** has gui functionality that is winscp like, as well.  To install:

   sudo apt-get install gftp-gtk
5. **sftp** - although not a gui it is worth mentioning.  You can connect a remote file system over the commandline using sftp.  By default this capability is enabled for all users in ubuntu if sftp is installed.
6. **sshfs** *`-- then use any file manager --`* my fav.  Sshfs is a user space tool for mounting directories on remote servers over ssh. You do not need to be root, just create a directory in your home directory and mount to it, e.g. mkdir ~/data

Installing sshfs:

```
sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

Examples of mounting remote directories:

```
sshfs user@server /local/mount/point
sshfs  me@datarepo.com:subdir/another_sub_dir  ~/data`
```

Browse the mounted directory with your file manager.  To remove this mount:

```
fusermount -u /local/mount/point
```

Remember the local mount point (directory) must exist before you can mount on it -- just like nfs.

Finally, I'm not providing KDE programs since Ubuntu is largely a gnome based file system.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sshfs.

`sudo apt-get install sshfs` - This command will install sshfs for you.

Then you just need to mount your ssh directory in your local filesystem, like this:

`sshfs user@server:/path/to/remote/dir /path/to/local/dir`

Where the local dir is the place you wish to mount your remote files.
You can then browse your remote files using PCManFM.
Hope this works for you.

PS - You can unmount the remote directory like this:
`fusermount -u /path/to/local/dir`