# Is there any SCP program available for Ubuntu that does not require SFTP on a remote host?

Tags: software-recommendation, scp

I need a program that can manage files on a remote device running Linux using SCP. The remote device runs OpenWrt. On Windows there is a perfect one WinSCP. it is weird that there is no native program that can be used.

The program should be able to:

- list files
- copy and move files to/from the device and within the device.
- delete files on the device
- view and edit files
- change file permissions

I have found only one alternative, except using CLI and installing WinSCP with wine.

It is Midnight Commander with `fish`. It works really poor. The problems are:

1. It mixes up `~` on a remote device and on the computer.
2. It can't edit files. I can open and edit, but they are saved to a wrong place.

There is a lot of other annoying problems that makes it almost unusable. I gave up using `mc` and now I am using pure shell on the remote device.

**Please do not tell me that Nautilus, etc support these features. They don't!!!**

Linux native file managers require SFTP that is not available on the remote device.

Maybe it is possible to get nautilus use SCP, but I did not find a way of doing it without changing sources.

## THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE !!!

I have a specific requirement that is not covered in the duplicate question.

If it is not possible on Ubuntu, then this could be an answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54657/discussion-on-question-by-pilot6-is-there-any-scp-program-available-for-ubuntu-t).

Comment: Related (but no valid answer): [GUI SCP Client?](/q/812960/175814)

Comment: GUI is not specifically required. It can be a terminal client. It is not very hard to write one. If Shell connection in MC worked better, it would be a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it working with the `mc` from `bionic` Ubuntu repo.

In `mc` select "Right Panel", then "Shell Connection" and type in the address. In my case it is `root@192.168.1.1`.

Enter the password when asked.

It seems that all is working, including view and edit. It didn't with older `mc` versions.

Answer (score 1):

Update : The problem here is that openwrt does not support linux clients without installing the sftp server.

See https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/sftp.server

openwrt has no intention of resolving this, see https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/4161

So, from the first link, the solution , server side, is to install `openssh-sftp-server`

```
opkg update
opkg install openssh-sftp-server
```

You can then use any number of graphical clients or sshfs - see [What is a program similar to WinSCP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94665/what-is-a-program-similar-to-winscp) and [What is a program similar to WinSCP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94665/what-is-a-program-similar-to-winscp/94673#94673)

Alternate is to use winscp with wine

```
sudo apt-get install wine
wine winscp.exe
```

Comment: That is wrong. Openwrt has SCP server. It does not have SFTP server.

Comment: The problem that I can't use SCP server on Ubuntu, except pure CLI. I can type scp commands in a terminal and do whatever I want, but there is no program that can do it. It can be a terminal prog, not a GUI.

Comment: I ask a question how to do it without using SFTP, Everyone tells me that I should use SFTP and VTC as a duplicate.

Comment: As was stated in the discussion (not by me) - "well, you are not satisfied. the problem is solved. your question is a duplicate, and the answer to your more specific question about avoiding sftp is that there is no program that works the same way as winscp in that respect" I agree, this question is about Ubuntu clients, and the ubuntu clients work, but you have to configure openwrt, which is not really ubuntu related.

Comment: My question is 100% valid and is not a duplicate, even if it does not have a positive answer.

Comment: scp is not a server. Using scp by itself does not accomplish what you want. WinSCP apparently does more than just scp supports.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen This answer does not have any value. I initially wrote that I am looking for a way without using SFTP. And also mentioned that WinSCP was a workaround. So what is the point of this answer?

Comment: The point of the answer is that "no, there isn't, and these are your options."

Answer (score 1):

[FAR Manager for Linux](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l/) recently got support of SCP. Currently it has bugs but you may try.

To install from PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:far2l-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install far2l
far2l
```

Then press Alt+F2 (you may need to disable "Run Application" hotkey).
Select NetRocks and press Shift+F4 to create a new connection config.

Comment: It seems to connect, but doesn't list files. It works using sftp.

Comment: I made an SCP connection and see an empty directory. But if I run `ls` and hide the panel by Ctrl+O, it shows the files. So it doesn't work properly yet.

Comment: Yes, it is not working well yet. The empty folder that you see is /root

Comment: Well, I can change it to something else in the connection settings, lile `/etc` but it is still empty.

Comment: `mc` with `fish` is working a bit better, but also with problems. At least it does show files.

Comment: I guess that fish/scp will anyway work with issues due to limitations of protocols.

Comment: I am testing it now with a new `mc` version. Seems OK so far.

Comment: Tanks a lot for the idea. I'll write my answer.

Comment: BTW KDE Dolphin (Konqueror) also must support FISH

Answer (score 0):

far2l mentioned above recently fixed a bunch of issues with SCP on openwrt/ddwrt hosts:
https://github.com/elfmz/far2l/issues/1434

You can give the latest version a try. Works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Mount external server using `sshfs`

After that, it is mounted to your filesystem, you can use any file browser of your choice.

Example:

```
sshfs user@server:/directory ~/remote_directory
```

To automate the process, add an entry in fstab

```
sshfs#user@server:/directory /home/your_local_user/directory fuse idmap=user 0 0
```

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54523/discussion-between-pilot6-and-bodhi-zazen