# How do I cd the remote server directory mounted through File/Nautilus?

Tags: filesystem, sftp

I mount my server drive through Nautilus as [What is a program similar to WinSCP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94665/what-is-a-program-similar-to-winscp) describes, then how do I cd the directory in Terminal? I don't want to double click a folder again and again.

Comment: OK - the errors you see come from permission restrictions. You mount as user `tianhe` but might not have proper access rights. Check the output of `ls -l` for the respective files.

Comment: @Fiximan I mount as `ubuntu`, the server account. The local terminal just shows my local id.

Comment: @pa4080 Hi there, would you like to take a look at this related question I asked just now? https://askubuntu.com/q/1155939/646012

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nautilus (and other file managers) have their mounts in `/run`

Try to search unter `/run/user/<UID>/gvfs/<mount>/`.

If you regularly need CLI commands, I'd suggest mounting from CLI, too.

Comment: Yes, I just found it on `/run/..` by right click "open at local terminal". But there's still a problem, I can't e.g. use sublime text to open the file directly. `subl .` doesn't work. Btw, what does mounting from CLI mean? The sshfs stuff?

Comment: CLI = command line interface. Yes, either `sshfs` or a `cifs`-mount, depending on the kind of network drive. I don't seem to fully understand your problem with opening a file. Could you elaborate some more? What errors do you see?

Comment: Oh, I see. I know what CLI means. I am just not familiar with `sshfs`, I will try later. With `sshfs`, I think maybe I will be able to open a remote file with my local editor e.g. sublime text `subl index.html`?

Comment: OK, let me upload a screenshot.

Comment: You already should be able open it with local editors when going via Nautilus and `/run` - assuming you do have the access rights on the network share. Permissions will be all the same between `sshfs` and a GUI Nautilus mount. `sshfs` will just mount is "like a local directory" and thus it'll behave as such.

Comment: Hmmm. My server username is `ubuntu`, local id is `tianhe`. When I connect to the server using Nautilus, I am required to input an server account. Then I used the "ubuntu" account. When I copy a file from local drive to server directory, the ownership automatically becomes "ubuntu".

Comment: And `www`-data often belongs to a `www`-user. You'll need to mount as some .... "higher authority", then, or give the user-ID you use for mounting group rights for the `www`-dir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95711/discussion-between-rick-and-fiximan).