# How can I, in Terminal use Sublime Text to open a remote directory mounted by Nautilus?

Tags: command-line, mount, nautilus, sftp, sublime-text

I mounted a remote server's drive through Nautilus. Login as `ubuntu`(server account). Local user id is `tianhe`.

I want to use sublime text CLI command (`subl file_to_open`) to open files on remote server. But I get `Permission denied` errors.

```
tianhe@tianhe-windy:/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=x.x.x.x/home/ubuntu/test$ subl .
cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```

**However, I can open and create files through Nautilus, by right click the same remote folder -> Open With Other Application -> Choose Sublime Text.**

---

Directory Permission see from server is:

```
ubuntu@VM-0-9-ubuntu:~/test$ ll
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jul  4 21:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x 8 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jul  4 21:23 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   16 Jul  4 21:42 haha.txt
```

Directory Permission see from local is:

```
tianhe@tianhe-windy:/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=x.x.x.x/home/ubuntu/test$ ll
total 9
drwxrwxr-x 1 tianhe tianhe 4096 7月   4 21:42 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 tianhe tianhe 4096 7月   4 21:23 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tianhe tianhe   16 7月   4 21:42 haha.txt
tianhe@tianhe-windy:/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=x.x.x.x/home/ubuntu/test$ subl .
cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied
tianhe@tianhe-windy:/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host=x.x.x.x/home/ubuntu/test$
```

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sublime text, but `.` usually means the current directory. Isn't the right command `subl haha.txt`?

Comment: Can you open files with other programs? E.g. CLI: `cat haha.txt` or `more haha.txt` then GUI: `gedit haha.txt`?

Comment: @pa4080 Yes it's the right command. Open a directory or a file are both correct.

Comment: @Fiximan Oh I seem to understand something. `cat` and `more` are ok. the GUI `gedit` also works. Now I think the problem is totally because of Sublime Text.

Comment: I tried VS code and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled the Sublime Text installed from Ubuntu Software and then reinstalled it according to the offcial doc from its official site, which essentially uses `apt`. And it works!